# Show there exist an positive integer $N$ such that $|e^z|>|\sum_{r=N}^{\infty}\frac{z^r}{r!}|$

Tags: complex-analysis

$z$ an complex number,
my question is how to show that there exist an positive integer $N$ such that $|e^z|>|\sum_{r=N}^{\infty}\frac{z^r}{r!}|$.

(We know $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^r}{r!}=e^z$)

How to show that there is an positive integer $N$ that satisfy the above partial sum?

Comment: Do you mean $r!$ or $r$ for your inequality?

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry for forgetting the factorial

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^r}{r!}$ converges for each z, so what can be said for the remainders $S_N:=\sum_{r=N}^{\infty}\frac{z^r}{r!}$ for fixed z?

Comment: What @cQQkie asked, plus the fact that $e^z\ne0$.

Comment: @cQQkie, sorry I didn't get it. Can you explain it more explicitly?

Comment: It's a standard observation that $S_N$ converges to $0$ for convergent series